# Propositional logic: Exclusive disjunction?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I would like to express formally the following disjunction:

Either A is the case or B is the case or C is the case and only one among A, B and C is the case. In other words: at least one among A, B and C is the case and only one of them is the case.

How do you express this formally? Is this equivalent to an exclusive disjunction?

Answer (score 2):

If you are thinking of doing $$A \ XOR \ B \ XOR \ C$$

... no, that doesn't work: a generalized XOR is true iff an *odd* number of its terms are true, so this expression would also be true if all of $A$, $B$, and $C$ are true.

I think your best option is just to go with something like

$$(A \land \neg B \land \neg C) \lor (\neg A \land B \land \neg C) \lor (\neg A \land \neg B \land C)$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand: how can all of A, B and C be true if I am using an exclusive "or"? Also the "odd" thing is not clear to me. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Fishermansfriend OK, work it out: $T \ XOR \ T \ XOR \ T= F \ XOR \ T = T$